# Core Data: Handling multiple profiles that can customize a prepopulated, static sql db?

Tags: ios, sql, core-data

Say I have an app that allows you to create a simple profile within core data that'll have different user attributes like name, sex, age, etc. This entity `Profile` is created and saved. Upon diving into the profile, a table view is presented of cars with data that's been generated from an imported sql database which was created using a utility app that prepopulated data using a core data model. Each `Car` has various attributes as well, such as make, model, year, color, etc.

Say I want to be able to click on each car in this tableview and select the field. While doing so, I want a variable `isSelected` to be set to `1` in order to keep track of which cars in this database have been selected by the user.

So far this would be simple to do using a single `Profile` with a to-many relationship:  `Profile <-->> Car`.

**Problem**
The issue I'm having is doing the above with *multiple* profiles.
Model is setup like `Profile <<-->> Car` - 
With multiple profiles, I can't figure out how to keep the imported sql database static (because this is the base data that every new profile will start out with) and then have another database or entity or something else i'm not thinking of with the `isSelected = 1 or 0` attribute for each `Car`.

At first I thought I could just create a copy of each `Car` by doing this:

```
Profile *_currentProfile;
for (loop through all cars in the db) {
  Car *copiedCar = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Car" inManagedObjectContext:self.appDelegate.managedObjectContext];
  copiedCar.make = originalCar.make;
  copiedCar.model = originalCar.model;
  ...
  [_currentProfile addCarObject:copiedCar];
}
```

I thought this would allow me to create a copy of each `Car` and put it into the current `Profile` and modify the `isSelected` attribute without affecting the original database. This could then allow more profiles to be made without them interfering with each other. The problem occurred when other profiles began doing fetch requests for the `Car`s. The fetch request from subsequent profiles which generate 2x, 3x, .., the number of available `Car`s depending on the number of profiles created, because each created profile would essentially generate another full list of `Car`s

**Question**
So my model is a bit more complex than this Car example above, but the idea is the same.. how should I structure the Core Data model to allow for multiple profiles to customize an existing core data sql database without the multiple customizations interfering with each Profile? There will be no log out / in function in this. The profiles will be on the main screen and you just select the one you wish to enter. Should I:

1. have separate sql databases for each profile created?
2. would a core data structure like this work: `Profile <<-->> Car <-->> Custom`
   With the `isSelected` attribute in the `Custom` entity?
3. something else I'm not thinking of...

I tried doing the first two, but I'm just not doing something right and got myself so confused.

Comment: So you might replace the prepopulated cars in future updates? A car connected to a profile means it's selected?

Comment: Yes to both.. The prepopulated car db would probably get updated in the future. And I want the selected Cars to be associated with the various profiles, without changing the original db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your cars have a relationship to profiles, then using those relationships changes the original data - so you can't just replace it (though you could run an update on the data).

If you want to keep the source data pristine such that you could delete all of the cars and replace them with other data then you would need to give each a unique identifier and then update the profiles with a list of identifiers. But, any update to the cars would still require them to retain the same identifiers.

So, all cars should have a unique identifier, and you should use many-many relationships. And you should get rid of any `isSelected` flags (because the relationships embody that information). The unique identifiers allow you to update the cars in the future without it mattering that they have relationships to profiles.

If your real problem is that each profile wants to change the car instances that it's connected to, then you should create a new entity which has a relationship to the car and profile entities (and which could replace the direct relationship between car and profile). That entity holds attributes that add to or override the car attributes. This new entity can be associated with only one car and one profile, and both should be required. Cars and profiles both have many instances of this new entity.

Comment: Thanks Wain, I'm still somewhat new to core data, so let me just try and comprehend what you're suggesting. I have a feeling your second suggestions is what I would want, but seems more confusing to me to implement:
1. unique identifier method - so you would do just as I did above in my example: create a copy of each car entity as they're selected, but then assign an identifier unique to that profile. This way, when other profiles try to fetch data from the original db, it would ignore those entities with a unique identifier attached?

Comment: No, create no copies. The unique identifiers just make life easy in the future when you want to update your 'static' data. The new entity, let's call it `CarConnection` is used to connect the profile to cars and add any information you want to the connection. For a profile, fetch only the `CarConnection`s connected to that profile.